# exclude a certain double character in a regex

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a regex.

so far my pattern looks like this ( Python Verbose flavor regex )

```
(?P<text>
 [a-zA-Z0-9]+        # can start with "core char"
 [a-zA-Z0-9\ \-]*     # can have a "core char" or space|dash within it
 [a-zA-Z0-9]+        # must end with a "core character"
)
```

I want to change this so within that middle section, I don't match on have a repeating space or dash.  Having multiple spaces/dashes within the text is acceptable.

good:

```
hello world
hello-world
h-ll-w-rld
```

bad:

```
-hello-world
hello--world
h-ll--w-rld
hello  world
```

Comment: A simple way might be to just add a second regex to retest the strings that pass through the first regex for double space/dash. Its not super efficient, but simple and quick to write.

Comment: Can't you just remove the `*` from the middle part, is hello-wo-rld acceptable?

Comment: The speed loss from @Dgrin91's suggestion would probably be minimal, while keeping your code more readable, modular, and easily maintainable.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia No, because then `hello-w-orld` would fail, even though it should work.

Comment: correct, `hello-w-orld` should work.  I'd prefer not to do a second regex, because it would be harder to integrate.  The code is set up as an object instance that has a configurable regex.  I'd have to rework the module itself and everything that calls it, in order to use 2 regexes ( or a function which runs the 2 regexes ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have something like the following:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\ \-]?)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

http://rubular.com/r/VGfGTrqayR

---

If you ALWAYS want to have 2 or more words, than you'd use the following instead

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\ \-])+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

http://rubular.com/r/EdV3iBQbsw

Comment: I think that is the idea, he does want something like that to work. Perhaps a better example is-something-like-this.

Comment: @ctn okay, I fixed that part.  although i'm not entirely sure that the OP wants to match `h`

Comment: oh that works.   thanks!

i also thought about using your original idea with an OR `^(([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\ \-]?)+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$`

Comment: @SamIam I was just mentioning it. Now your answer is the most complete :)

Comment: perfect. thank you!  i never thought of wrapping the first 2 parts into a group.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
(?P<text>
 [a-zA-Z0-9]+
 ([ -][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*
)
```

Comment: Oh right, the * allows for 0. In that case nevermind, I was wrong.

Comment: This matches `0` and `h`.  only `h` should match.  sooo close.

Comment: Why do you not want `0`? What are the exact rules? Are numbers acceptable at all?